# Django DRF, how to present new enriched fields in my endpoints?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to do the following exercise, taking into account my 3 base models, Room, Event, Book.

I have two user roles, 'business' and 'customers'

The business can create a room with M capacity

- The business can create events for every room.
- The business can delete a room if said room does not have any events.
- A customer can book a place for an event.
- A customer can cancel its booking for an event.
- A customer can see all the available public events.

My models extract:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.id) + ' capacity: ' + str(self.capacity))

class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.date) + '  - Room: ' + str(self.room.id))
    
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.event.date) + '- Client: ' + self.user.username)
```

And my serializers:

```
from .models import Room, Event, Book
from rest_framework import serializers

class RoomListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'

class BookListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'user')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'user')

class EventListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BookListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='book_set')
    rooms = RoomListSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='room_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'room', 'date', 'rooms', 'private', 'books')

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would like Event to derive the field capacity from Room. and be able to display it in my json response.

I have this code extract in my views:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = EventListSerializer
    queryset = Event.objects.select_related('room', 'book')
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return EventListSerializer
        return EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Event.objects.select_related('room')

        if self.request.GET.get('date'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(date=self.request.GET.get('date'))
        else:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('-id')
        return queryset

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).exclude(private=True)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

how should I approach this, where would my logic take, for example I would like to add to the **json** of **EventListSerializer** the field of `space_avalible = room.capacity - Book.related_set.filter(Event.room=Room.Id).count()`
how could i achieve this?

Comment: what's this `Book.related_set.filter(Event.room=Room.Id).count()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `space_available` information to the serializer using [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) so:

```
class EventSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    space_available = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_space_available(self, instance):
        return instance.room.capacity - instance.book_set.count()
```

Comment: thanks, work me thhi is code:
´´´
def get_spaces_available(self, instance):
        return instance.room.capacity - instance.book_set.count()
´´´